# using the value of a variable from one function within a second function in R

Tags: r, function, parameters

This is probably a very simple answer but can't seem to find a solution. I have a function which gives a set of parameters:

```
theta <-
function(
e = 0.2,l= 0.01,p= 0.05)
return(c(e=e,l=l,p=p))
```

So I can return from it a set of parameters, whilst changing one or more of them, e.g. by using

```
theta(e=0.1) #or
theta(l=0.1)
```

My problem is I want to call this function inside another function, where an input for that function is one of the variables.

So for example a function such as:

```
randFunc<-function(parameter,value){
s<-theta(parameter=value)
return(s)
}
```

Then use

```
randFunc("e",0.1) #or
randFunc("l",0.3)
```

However i'll get the error "Error in theta(parameter = value) : unused argument (parameter = value)"

I've tried a few things but can't seem to get the parameter "value" to be used within the theta function.

Comment: Sorry that should read 
    randFunc("e",0.1) #or
    randFunc("l",0.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a string in the call to `randFunc`, because the parameter you put in does not exist. Then, within the function you can use `eval(parse(text = "something"))` to use it as a non-string input for the `theta` function.

```
randFunc<-function(parameter,value){
  s<-theta(eval(parse(text = parameter)) = value)
  return(s)
}
```

and then call it with

```
randFunc("e", 0.1)
```

---

@Cath provided a solution without the use of `eval(parse())`:

Change your `randFunc` to:

```
randFunc<-function(parameter,value){
  s <- theta()
  s[parameter] <- value
  return(s)
}
```

This is pretty elegant and will definitely find its way into future functions of my own (or even into current functions when it is time for revision).

Comment: Hmm, a quick google query showed me that this has something to do with `eval(parse))` being suboptimal. Is there a better way to overcome this quite common problem? I'm asking because `eval(parse())` can be found embarassingly often in my own functions...

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use do.call:

```
randFunc <- function(parameter, value){
    L = list(value)
    names(L) <- parameter
    do.call(theta, L)
}

> randFunc('e', 0.1)
   e    l    p 
0.10 0.01 0.05 
> randFunc('l', 0.3)
   e    l    p 
0.20 0.30 0.05
```

Comment: Thanks Johan, this is also a great answer